# Uploaded pictures are fully white

Tags: bug, images

The past few days I encountered a strange problem:

When I attempted to upload certain pictures in order to add them to a question ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377491/linear-color-gradient-not-working) in particular), the uploaded files were fully white.

On my computer, these files (BMPs, exported by SDL2) are displayed correctly. However, after they were uploaded to Imgur, they were white. I used wget to download one of these files and they stayed white locally, so it's no linking or display issue.

Other pictures (other BMPs, PNGs or JPEGs) are working without problem, only the pictures exported from SDL create this issue, as you can (not) see in the image below:

<kbd>[image: Elephant valley of the mandelbrot set]</kbd>
Behold this pretty picture of an area of the elephant valley in the mandelbrot set

Here you can see part of the hex representation of the downloaded PNG (!):
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Why does this happen to certain files? In the question mentioned above, I uploaded the pictures into my Dropbox Public folder and linked them drom there.

**Edit:** When I open such an image in GIMP and export it as-is, the binary looks a lot differently (only RGB, without Alpha) and can be uploaded to any SE site without problems.

Comment: The converter used by Imgur to change BMP to PNG probably does not support alpha channel for BMP images or the BMP image has the wrong header info (version).

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Were you ever able to figure out a solution to this?

Comment: As I already wrote, I opened and reexported the files in GIMP, with which the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Using what @Spokey said, I figured out a way to remove alpha channel from the bmp.

The only way I found a way around this was to use cimg. I did the following:

```
CImg<float> image("image.bmp");
image = image.sRGBtoRGB();
image.save("image.bmp");

...
//upload to imgur
```